# c# Problem reading MongoDb data as name + value

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using c# to read data from MongoDb and I've run into a situation where the data for one of my keys: GoodsList is being read in this form:

```
"goodsList": [
      [
        {
          "name": "name",
          "value": "testName"
        },
        {
          "name": "price",
          "value": 32
        },
        {
          "name": "number",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "id",
          "value": 68345
        },
        {
          "name": "cate_id",
          "value": 6208
        },
        {
          "name": "image",
          "value": "/testimg.png"
        },
        {
          "name": "use_property",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "props_text",
          "value": "standardtext，standardtext2"
        },
        {
          "name": "props",
          "value": [
            582,
            585
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
```

But I don't want this, I want it to be read in this format below:

```
"StatusText": "Finished",
  "GoodsList": [
    {
      "name": "testName",
      "price": 32,
      "number": 1,
      "id": 68345,
      "cate_id": 6208,
      "image": "/testimg.png",
      "use_property": 1,
      "props_text": "standardtext，standardtext2",
      "props": [
        582,
        585
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Notes": "this.form.remark",
```

How can I set the correct format for reading? I've tried reading it as BsonArray or BsonDocument or directly as an entity class (GoodsList in entity class as BsonArray or BsonDocument), but it doesn't work, either I get a conversion error or the result is still the same.

Comment: I believe that you are querying and reading the collection as `BsonDocument` (`db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("<collection name>")`). You should create the model class and read the collection document as that class. `db.GetCollection<Model>("<collection name>")`. The `GoodsList` should use the model class instead of `BsonArray`/`BsonDocument`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you should create your own model classes, same goes for `GoodsList`.

When you are using `BsonArray`/`BsonDocument` and serialize the result, it will show the objects containing the `Key` and `Value` properties.

Your model classes should be as below:

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

[BsonNoId]
public class Goods
{
    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("price")]
    public int Price { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("cate_id")]
    public int CateId { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("image")]
    public string Image { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("use_property")]
    public int UseProperty { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("props_text")]
    public string PropsText { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("props")]
    public List<int> Props { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("StatusText")]
    public string StatusText { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("GoodsList")]
    public List<Goods> GoodsList { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Notes")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
IMongoDatabase db = /* IMongoDatabase instance */;
IMongoCollection<Root> collection = db.GetCollection<Root>("<collection name>");

var result = collection.Find(/* Filter criteria */)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you! My problem has been solved. The data consistency issue on write and read is now realized by improving my own model class. Previously I used a similar model class, but it didn't work, and now it looks like it should be a matter of not adding [BsonElement("xxxx")] for the sub-property Good.